# How to pass parameters and data to objective function for optimization with NLopt

Tags: julia, nlopt

In Julia v0.3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04, I need to pass parameters and data to an objective function for use in an optimisation routine using NLopt in Julia. The following example code demonstrates how I currently do this:

```
function estimate(myModel, myData, myInitialValue, nloptAlgorithm, numberOfParameters)
    opt = Opt(nloptAlgorithm, numberOfParameters)
    localObjectiveFunction = ((param, grad) -> generic_objective_function(param, grad, myModel, myData))
    min_objective!(opt, localObjectiveFunction)
    (objFuncOpt, paramOpt, flag) = optimize(opt, myInitialValue)
end
function generic_objective_function(param, grad, myModel, myData)
    #some code
end
```

This works, although suffers from the issue that `localObjectiveFunction` is anonymous so the compiler will not be able to determine the output type of the function at run-time, which in turn has performance implications.

I'm simply wondering if there is a better way to deal with this problem? Should I be using `FastAnonymous`? Or is there another form of magic that gets around this issue?

Comment: I'd recommend [profiling](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/profile/) your script to check for bottlenecks rather than blindly making optimizations.

Comment: @FelipeLema *Case 1*: A small number of optimisations on a complex objective function. *Case 2*: A large number of optimisations on a very simple objective function. I agree that for *Case 1* the penalty is barely measurable. However, for *Case 2* it can be significant (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356437/julia-compiler-does-not-appear-to-optimize-when-a-function-is-passed-a-function)). Admittedly, most of my personal problems fall in the *Case 1* category. Nonetheless, I'm genuinely curious if there is a work-around for *Case 2*. So the question stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Julia v0.5, this question will be superfluous. [This pull request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13412) on github fixes the performance issues with anonymous functions, so from v0.5 onwards, just use anonymous functions!