# Puzzling results for Julia typeof

Tags: julia

I am puzzled by the following results of `typeof` in the Julia 1.0.0 REPL:

```
# This makes sense.   
julia> typeof(10)
Int64

# This surprised me.
julia> typeof(function)
ERROR: syntax: unexpected ")"

# No answer at all for return example and no error either.
julia> typeof(return)

# In the next two examples the REPL returns the input code.    
julia> typeof(in)
typeof(in)

julia> typeof(typeof)
typeof(typeof)

# The "for" word returns an error like the "function" word.
julia> typeof(for)
ERROR: syntax: unexpected ")"
```

The Julia 1.0.0 [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.typeof) says for `typeof` 
 "Get the concrete type of x."

The `typeof(function)` example is the one that really surprised me.  I expected a `function` to be a first-class object in Julia and have a type.  I guess I need to understand types in Julia.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Per some comment questions below, here is an example based on a small function:

```
julia> function test() return "test"; end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test()
"test"

julia> typeof(test)
typeof(test)
```

Based on this example, I would have expected `typeof(test)` to return `generic function`, not `typeof(test)`.

Comment: What is your expectation for `typeof(function)`? I.e., what did you expect the returned value would be?

Comment: Some kind of type name that a function is a type of.

Comment: I'm no Julia expert, but isn't `function` just a keyword to begin a definition of a function, not a function itself?

Comment: What does `typeof` show for an actual named function, or an anonymous function?

Comment: It is not the `function` keyword being the first-class citizen. The *functions* are the [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in Julia. The `function` keyword is not *a* function. What you expected is *the* keyword `function` to be *a* function, which is not. There are even functional programming languages without such a `function` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for comment.  I edited my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Yeah, that is kinda weird.  Why wouldn't `f()::Int64 = 1; typeof(f)` return something like `function of type Int64`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs every function is a different type so that type-specialization optimizes functions inside of other functions.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be clear, I am not a hardcore user of the Julia internals. What follows is an answer designed to be (hopefully) an intuitive explanation of what functions are in Julia for the non-hardcore user. I do think this (very good) question could also benefit from a more technical answer provided by one of the more core developers of the language. Also, this answer is longer than I'd like, but I've used multiple examples to try and make things as intuitive as possible.

As has been pointed out in the comments, `function` itself is a reserved keyword, and is not an actual function istself *per se*, and so is orthogonal to the actual question. This answer is intended to address your edit to the question.

Since Julia v0.6+, `Function` is an abstract supertype, much in the same way that `Number` is an abstract supertype. All functions, e.g. `mean`, user-defined functions, and anonymous functions, are subtypes of `Function`, in the same way that `Float64` and `Int` are subtypes of `Number`.

This structure is deliberate and has several advantages.

Firstly, for reasons I don't fully understand, structuring functions in this way was the key to allowing anonymous functions in Julia to run just as fast as in-built functions from `Base`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356437/julia-compiler-does-not-appear-to-optimize-when-a-function-is-passed-a-function) and [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13412) as starting points if you want to learn more about this.

Secondly, because each function is its own subtype, you can now dispatch on specific functions. For example:

```
f1(f::T, x) where {T<:typeof(mean)} = f(x)
```

and:

```
f1(f::T, x) where {T<:typeof(sum)} = f(x) + 1
```

are different dispatch methods for the function `f1`

So, given all this, why does, e.g. `typeof(sum)` return `typeof(sum)`, especially given that `typeof(Float64)` returns `DataType`? The issue here is that, roughly speaking, from a syntactical perspective, `sum` needs to serves two purposes simultaneously. It needs to be both a value, like e.g. `1.0`, albeit one that is used to call the `sum` function on some input. But, it is also needs to be a type name, like `Float64`.

Obviously, it can't do both at the same time. So `sum` on its own behaves like a value. You can write `f = sum ; f(randn(5))` to see how it behaves like a value. But we also need some way of representing the type of `sum` that will work not just for `sum`, but for any user-defined function, and any anonymous function. The developers decided to go with the (arguably) simplest option and have the type of `sum` print literally as `typeof(sum)`, hence the behaviour you observe. Similarly if I write `f1(x) = x ; typeof(f1)`, that will also return `typeof(f1)`.

Anonymous functions are a bit more tricky, since they are not named as such. What should we do for `typeof(x -> x^2)`? What actually happens is that when you build an anonymous function, it is stored as a temporary global variable in the module `Main`, and given a number that serves as its type for lookup purposes. So if you write `f = (x -> x^2)`, you'll get something back like `#3 (generic function with 1 method)`, and `typeof(f)` will return something like `getfield(Main, Symbol("##3#4"))`, where you can see that `Symbol("##3#4")` is the temporary type of this anonymous function stored in `Main`. (a side effect of this is that if you write code that keeps arbitrarily generating the same anonymous function over and over you will eventually overflow memory, since they are all actually being stored as separate global variables of their own type - however, this does *not* prevent you from doing something like this `for n = 1:largenumber ; findall(y -> y > 1.0, x) ; end` inside a function, since in this case the anonymous function is only compiled once at compile-time).

Relating all of this back to the `Function` supertype, you'll note that `typeof(sum) <: Function` returns `true`, showing that the type of `sum`, aka `typeof(sum)` is indeed a subtype of `Function`. And note also that `typeof(typeof(sum))` returns `DataType`, in much the same way that `typeof(typeof(1.0))` returns `DataType`, which shows how `sum` actually behaves like a value.

Now, given everything I've said, all the examples in your question now make sense. `typeof(function)` and `typeof(for)` return errors as they should, since `function` and `for` are reserved syntax. `typeof(typeof)` and `typeof(in)` correctly return (respectively) `typeof(typeof)`, and `typeof(in)`, since `typeof` and `in` are both functions. Note of course that `typeof(typeof(typeof))` returns `DataType`.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks Colin for that superb answer.  As a newcomer to Julia it was truly educational.

Comment: Your answer almost covered everything, but there is one small point that is still puzzling: `typeof(return)` outputs nothing at all.  Maybe the reason for this should now be obvious to me, but it is not.

Comment: Julia's JIT compiler compiles typeof(return) on the REPL command line and simply returns when it encounters the return command, thus shortcutting typeof().

Comment: @Bill Thanks Bill!  I suspected something like that was going on, but was not sure.